# Отображение модуля Joomla на отдельной странице

Tags: php, joomla, cms

Написал модуль для joomla выводящий кое какую информацию из базы данных. Разместил её на определённой позиции в шаблоне.
 Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы модель имел ещё одну целую страницу для вывода информации из базы данных. То есть, я не понимаю как заставить вызывать модуль и его определённое представление из созданного материала.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение проблемы. В материалах создаём статью, а в ней размещаем модуль {loadmodule mod_ule}. А в точке входа в модуль, определяем откуда вызван модуль и выбираем нужное представление.

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$view  = $input->getString('view');
```

Модуль вызванный из материалов всегда имеет `$view == "article"`